# Is this example of countably infinite union of closed subsets of the reals closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is the following set $S\subset \mathbb{R}$ closed with respect to $\mathbb{R}$ ?

$$S = \left\{ 0 \right\} \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\left [ \frac{1}{2^{2i+1}},\frac{1}{2^{2i}} \right ]$$

For context, I'm trying to understand how to approach a proof for the Heine-Borel theorem, and thought it may be instructive to try and fail to create a counter-example.

Comment: Yes, this set is closed. In fact, the set is perfect (closed -- each limit point of the set belongs to the set -- AND dense-in-itself -- each point of the set is a limit point of the set). Maybe someone will know a more elegant way, but one way is to show that each point NOT in the set is at a positive distance from the set.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro thank you, I wasn't aware of the concept of a perfect set and  dense-in-itself-ness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_n$ be a sequence in $S$ converging to some point $x$.  We will try to show that $x \in S$.

$S$ is contained in the closed set $[0,1]$, so necessarily  $x \in [0,1]$.  If $x=0$ we are done because $0 \in S$, so suppose instead that $x > 0$.  Choose a $k$ so large that $1/2^{2k+1} < x$.  Then we have $x_n \ge 1/2^{2k+1}$ for all but finitely many $n$, so that for all such $n$ we have $x_n \in S_k := \bigcup_{i=1}^k \left[\frac{1}{2^{2i+1}}, \frac{1}{2^{2i}}\right] \subset S$.  But $S_k$ is closed, as it is a finite union of closed sets, and $x$ is the limit of a sequence of points in $S_k$.  So in this case we must have $x \in S_k$ and in particular $x \in S$.

Comment: Thank you, the construction of S_k in this proof helped me see, using similar reasoning, why a finite number of open subsets would be sufficient to cover S (since any open subset used to cover the element 0 will contain an open ball of some radius r around 0, leaving a finite number of open intervals needed to cover the remaining closed intervals of S).

Comment: @Amral: Indeed.  Actually I started by thinking out how to prove that the set is compact, and then simplified the proof to show instead that it is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Its complement is the union of open intervals: $$(-\infty,0)\cup \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{2^{2i+2}}, \frac{1}{2^{2i+1}}\right) \cup \left( \frac{1}{4}, \infty\right)$$

Comment: I found this a helpful answer alongside @Nate 's , thank you, apologies that I can't accept both.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that $S = [0,+\infty[$, so $S$ is closed (take $x>0$ and prove $x\in S$. It is always instructive to fail to create a counter-example. Be lucky!

Comment: No point in the set is greater than $\frac 14$, so the claim is not correct.

Comment: Right. Clear I was sleeping. May be $S=[0,1/4]$ is better

Comment: S is a subset of [0, 1/4] , but it doesn't equal it. There are a countably infinite number of gaps.

Comment: I apologize. Please, forget my answers.